# Meteor query by array attribute

Tags: meteor

Suppose I have my collection as follows:

```js
{ 
"_id" : "PipdmEzTMAziXjWBn", 
"text" : "jkhkj",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-27T13:43:22.856Z"),
 "hashtags" : [ "fwXJcu5CpKcYZpQ3v", "DCS4eLNiS7NjipiDQ" ] }
```

The important thing here is that i store id's of hashtags as an array. 
Suppose I have a hashtag id as my input, how do I find all records that contain that id?

EDIT:

With the help of @zim, I did this:

```js
Feeds.find({hashtags: {$in: "DCS4eLNiS7NjipiDQ"}});
```

But now it says:

```js
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'feeds.findByHashtag' Error: $in needs an array
```

Answer (score 2):

for a top-level query, you can use $in. e.g.

```
let hashtagId = ['abc123'];
collection.find({hashtags: {$in: hashtagId}});
```

Comment: alright, i needed to put hashtagId into array, e.g [hashtagId], and it worked. Thanks for your help, you can edit your answer, I will accept it then